# Interop.Office error after converting project to VS 2010 from VS 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, interop

We have a VB.net project of VS 2008. Now i have converted it to VS 2010. After conversion  I have added reference to 2010 excela and word dlls. But now i am able to build the project but while running code i get error like

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.Office, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So how it can be solved ?What i am missing ?

Comment: Hard to guess why you "added" DLLs, you should not be doing that.  Google "embed interop types" to learn what is new since VS2010.

Comment: @HansPassant I have added Microsoft object library 14.0 too. Still error comes only when running project. But building project is successfull.